# div innerhtml not taking html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to update innerhtml of div with id NotifyDiv

I want to change it with following html code.

```
$html="<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>";
```

I am using following code to change it.

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML='$html'</script>";
```

But no changes occur.
However it I remove id = 'js-news' from the above ul tag it works.But I'll need the id.

Comment: Please post the UL structure.

Comment: try to use html() instead of innerHtml

Comment: @John: no jQuery tag, so it's unsafe to assume OP is using jQ here, and there is no `HTMLElement.html` method in the standard DOM API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source code of your browser you will see this:

```
<script>document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML='<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>'</script>
```

So we can see that in the JavaScript string you are using apotrophes, but the string is already encloded with apostrophes, so it attempts to end the string early: (before the letter j in js-news)

```
'<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>'
```

This can be solved by using escaped quotation marks for the JS string:

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML=\"$html\"</script>";
```

Comment: Then change the value of `$html` to contain double quotes, and you're back to square one... just use `json_encode`, it's the best tool for this type of job

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the code you have causes a syntax error in JS:

```
echo "...innerHTML='$html'</script>";
```

expands to:

```
             // opening '  closing ' => js-news === syntax error!
             //   \/       \/       
echo "...innerHTML='<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>'</script>";
```

Resulting JS code:

```
document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML='<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>'
```

The syntax highlighting shows the problem
Note the single quotes around `$html` and the single quotes *inside* the `$html` string. The best way to echo PHP values in JS would be to use `json_encode`:

```
echo "...document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML=", json_encode($html), "</script>";
```

The output should be something like:

```
<script>document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML="<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!<\/li><\/ul>"</script>
```

Now, those slashes are escaped, and you probably don't want that. Thankfully, there's a second parameter you can pass to [`json_encode`: cf the docs](http://www.php.net/json_encode). Passing `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` is what you need to do here:

```
$html="<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML=".json_encode($html, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)."</script>";
```

The output:

```
<script>document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML="<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>"</script>
```

## [DEMO](https://eval.in/287018)

Answer (score 0):

Perfect ans to your query is as under (just copy n paste and check it)

```
<?php
$html="<ul id='js-news'><li>HELLO WORLD!</li></ul>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML="<?php echo $html; ?>";
</script>";
```

Comment: Mukta Chourishi if solution is useful, please tick This answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass PHP variable with PHP syntax that is `<?php ?>`

Even if we can mix PHP, JavaScript and HTML together, we need to initialize proper languages before using their variables in case of JavaScript and PHP.

So, final code should be:

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('NotifyDiv').innerHTML = '<?php echo $html;?>'</script>";
```

Otherwise, everything looks correct.